# How to calculate and interpret a marginal treatment effect (local instrumental variable)? (Intuition through simple example.)

Tags: marginal, instrumental-variable, treatment-effect

I am working on the intuition behind local instrumental variables (LIV), also known as the marginal treatment effect (MTE). I have worked some time on this and would benefit from solving a simple. I hope I may get input on where my example goes awry.

As a starting point the standard local average treatment effect (LATE) is the treatment among individuals induced to take treatment by the instrument ("compliers"), while MTE is the limit form of LATE.

A [helpful](https://www.healthcare-economist.com/2013/06/11/local-instrumental-variables-2/) distinction between LATE and MTE is found between the questions:

- LATE: What is the difference in the treatment effect between those who are more likely to receive treatment compared to others?
- MTE: What is the difference in the treatment effect between those who are *marginally* more likely to receive treatment compare to others?

The term "marginally" is key and what it specifically implies in this context eludes me (in economics I am used to understanding it as the change in one variable given a one unit change in another). From what I gather, under MTE it is the change in outcome with a marginal change in the *probability* of receiving treatment, although I am not sure if this is correct. If it is correct I am not sure how to argue for policy or clinical relevance.

To understand the mechanics and interpretation of MTE I have set up a simple example that starts with the MTE estimator (from [Cornelissen et al. 2016](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0927537116300562)):

$MTE(X=x, U_{D}=p) = \frac{\partial E(Y | X=x, P(Z)=p)}{\partial p}$

Where $X$ is covariates of interest, $U_{D}$ is the "unobserved distaste for treatment" (not intuitively explained what implies), $Y$ is the outcome, and $P(Z)$ is the probability of treatment (propensity score).

Specifically, [Shafrin (2007)](https://www.healthcare-economist.com/2007/11/06/local-instrumental-variables/) state,

> The LIV [MTE] estimates the derivative of the expected outcome
> conditional on observed characteristics and the probability of
> electing to be in the treatment group, $E(Y|X=x, P(z,x))$, with
> respect to the probability of treatment.

**Example**

We want to estimate the MTE of college ($D=(0,1)$) on earnings ($Y>0$), using the continous variable distance to college ($Z$) as the instrument. We start by obtaining the propensity score $P(Z)$, which I read as equal to the predicted value of treatment from the standard first stage in 2SLS:

$ D= \alpha + \beta Z + \epsilon$

$=\hat{D}=P(Z)$

Now, to understand how to specifically estimate MTE, it would be helpful to think of the MTE for a specific set of observations defined by specific values of $X$ and $P(Z)$. Suppose there is only one covariate ($X$) necessary to condition on and that for the specific subset at hand we have $X=5$ and $P(Z)=.6$. Consequently, we have

$MTE(5, .6) = \frac{\partial E(Y | X=5, P(Z)=.6)}{\partial .6}$

Suppose further that $Y$ for the subset of observations defined by $(X=5,P(Z)=.6)$ is 15000,

$MTE(5, .6) = \frac{\partial 15000}{\partial .6}$

My understanding of this partial derivate is that the current set up is invalid, while substituting $\partial .6$ with $\partial p$ would simply result in 0 as it would be the derivate of a constant. I therefore wonder whether anyone has input on where I went wrong, and how I might arrive at MTE for this simple example.

Note that this post is moved from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493621/how-to-calculate-and-interpret-a-marginal-treatment-effect-local-instrumental-v?noredirect=1#comment913622_493621) as this community may be more familiar with MTE.